# Display table in td of another table onclick

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a table that has rows with number of times data is found. After clicking on a link that has the number, a second table is deployed to show the number of rows. This action works perfectly if the table has only one row but if it has more than one row after clicking on a link the table deploys in all rows not only in the relevent row. How can I solve this problem?

1- table

```
<table >
<tr>
<th>date</th>
<th>medicine</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($rows as $row)
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row->date_val;?></td>
<td>
<?=$row->medicine;?>
<a id="<?=$row->medicine?>"  class="deploy-medicine" title="Deploy" style="cursor:pointer"><?=$row->Total;?></a>
<div  class="toggle-medicine" style="display:none"></div>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
```

2-JQUERY

```
$('.deploy-medicine').click(function() {
var medicine = $(this).attr('id');
$.get( "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/get_medicine_name?medicine="+medicine, function( data ){
$(".toggle-medicine").html(data).slideToggle("slow"); 
}); 

});
```

3-controller

```
public function get_medicine_name()
{
$medicine =$this->input->get('medicine');
$data['medicine'] = $this->model_admin->get_medicine($medicine);
$this->load->view('medicine',$data);
}
```

4- MODEL

```
function get_medicine($data)
{
$this->db->select('inserted_time,operator');
$this->db->from('table_medicine');
$this->db->where('medicine',$data);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();    
}
```

5- the view that contain the table after click

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>date</th>
<th>Operador</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($medicine as $row)

{
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row->inserted_time?></td>
<td><?=$row->operator?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Confirm that you are actually getting the variable `medicine` in `get_medicine` with an echo. Also is `medicine` unique?

Comment: medicine is not unique, each row is a different medicine name. Yes I get it in get_medicine properly. My goal is done only when I have one row but if I have more, after clicking the toggle is made in all rows. My problem is in the JQUERY function. I don't know how to deploy the result in only one td when there are many rows.

Comment: You really should make that clearer in your question as your question makes it sound like you want to get just one and instead you are getting all medicines (php issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the closest `td` and find the `.toggle-medicine` selector in that.

This will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deploy-medicine").click(function() {
    console.log('deploying...');
    var medicine = $(this).attr("id");
    var el = $(this).closest('td').find('.toggle-medicine');
    el.html("Hello World").show();
  });
});
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoowPy